# binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'temperature_stats' (or there is no acceptable conversion), line 36

Tags: c++

I'm getting two errors with this code, the two errors are:

no operator "<<" matches these operands [**Line 36**]

binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'temperature_stats' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  [**Line 37**]

However, it's trying to output the result of a function, so I have no idea what is really causing the problem.

For the code, assume that the file location is correct and works properly

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct temperature_stats {
    string month;
    int hi_temp = 0;
    int low_temp = 0;
};

temperature_stats months_per_year[12];

void loadData(ifstream& inFile, temperature_stats[], int& size);
temperature_stats averageHigh(temperature_stats array[], int size);
temperature_stats averageLow(temperature_stats array[], int size);

temperature_stats averageHigh(temperature_stats array[], int month) {
    // this function calculates and returns the high temperature and the corresponding month of the year
    return array[month];
}

temperature_stats averageLow(temperature_stats array[], int month) {
    // this function calculates and returns the low temperature and the corresponding month of the year
    return array[month];
}

int main() {
    ifstream inFile;

    int rows = 12;

    loadData(inFile, months_per_year, rows);

    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
        cout << "The highest temperature recorded in the month of " << months_per_year[j].month << " was "
            << averageHigh(months_per_year, j) << endl;
    }

    inFile.close();

}

void loadData(ifstream& inFile, temperature_stats[], int& size) {
// this function reads and sorts data from a text file
    inFile.open(); // file location, can be interchangable if needed

    if (!inFile) {
        cout << "404 ERROR: FILE NOT FOUND\n" << endl; // debug line
    }

    if (inFile) {
        cout << "FILE FOUND!\n" << endl; // debug line
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        inFile >> months_per_year[i].month >> months_per_year[i].hi_temp >> months_per_year[i].low_temp;
        cout << months_per_year[i].month << " " << months_per_year[i].hi_temp << " " 
            << months_per_year[i].low_temp << endl; // debug line
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `<<` to do, with a `temperature_stats`? C++ can't possibly know how to `<<` a `temperature_stats` into `std::cout`, or any other stream. You have to tell your C++ compiler how that should work.

Comment: _"However, it's trying to output the result of a function, so I have no idea what is really causing the problem."_ -- Why do you have no idea? Are you not aware that the result of the function is of type 'temperature_stats', perfectly matching the compiler message?

Answer (score 1):

The result you're trying to print is a struct, and C++ doesn't know how to do complex, user-defined values automatically.

The `<<` really isn't magic, it's actually a clever way of providing a function for writing to an output stream (`ostream`), and you can overload the operator to print your type like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const temperature_stats& ts) {
    os << "Temperature: "
      << ts.month
      << " low: " << ts.low_temp
      << " high: " << ts.hi_temp;
    return os;
}
```